# Как узнать название сессии (session name) при создании приложения Telegram?

Tags: telegram, telethon

Я зарегистрировал в telegram новое приложение. После этого мне стала доступна вся необходимая информация (api_id, api_hash) кроме названия сессии. Я не понимаю где его можно посмотреть? Мне оно нужно для библиотеки питоновской библиотеки Telethon

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте файл config, а нем пишете это заменив апишки на свои:

```
# file: config.py

API_ID = API_ID
API_HASH = 'API_HASH'
```

Затем создаёте ещё один файл и в него пишете это и запускаете:

```
# file: login.py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from config import (API_ID, API_HASH)

# Авторизация и печать ключа сессии
with TelegramClient(StringSession(), API_ID, API_HASH) as client:
    print(client.session.save())
```